# Как настроить фон терминалу в ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

Когда заходишь в параметры терминала нет вкладки Фон, как в прошлых версиях. Есть ли другая возможность поставить фон? (Кроме ставить старые версии убунты)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Вот]

Comment: кто вообще ставит фон в терминалах?

Comment: Все кто хочет настроить себе приятный интерфейс

Comment: Проверю завтра есть ли такое, сейчас не могу

Comment: @meine, почитайте внимательно правила.  Вопросы по администрированию (и следовательно настройке инструменария) разрешены

Comment: Добавил скрины с настройками

Comment: @finally, полупрозрачный терминал например очень удобен, чтобы не альттабаться.